# Make elements NA depending on a predicate function

Tags: r, na

How can I easily change elements of a list or vectors to `NAs` depending on a predicate ?

I need it to be done in a single call for smooth integration in `dplyr::mutate` calls etc...

expected output:

```
make_na(1:10,`>`,5)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA

my_list <- list(1,"a",NULL,character(0))    
make_na(my_list, is.null)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]
# character(0)
```

*Note:*

*I answered my question as I have one solution figured out but Id be happy to get alternate solutions. Also maybe this functionality is already there in base R or packaged in a prominent library*

*Was inspired by my frustration in [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659096/convert-na-to-most-appearing-value-based-in-another-column/50659202?noredirect=1#comment88340457_50659202)*

Answer (score 1):

We can build the following function:

```
make_na <- function(.x,.predicate,...) {
  is.na(.x) <- sapply(.x,.predicate,...)
  .x
}
```

Or a bit better to leverage `purrr`'s magic :

```
make_na <- function(.x,.predicate,...) {
  if (requireNamespace("purrr", quietly = TRUE)) {
    is.na(.x) <- purrr::map_lgl(.x,.predicate,...)
  } else {
    if("formula" %in% class(.predicate))
      stop("Formulas aren't supported unless package 'purrr' is installed") 
    is.na(.x) <- sapply(.x,.predicate,...)
  }
  .x
}
```

This way we'll be using  `purrr::map_lgl` if library `purrr` is available, `sapply` otherwise.

Some examples :

```
make_na <- function(.x,.predicate,...) {
  is.na(.x) <- purrr::map_lgl(.x,.predicate,...)
  .x
}
```

Some use cases:

```
make_na(1:10,`>`,5)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA

my_list <- list(1,"a",NULL,character(0))
make_na(my_list, is.null)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]
# character(0)

make_na(my_list, function(x) length(x)==0)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] NA
```

If `purrr` is installed we can use this short form:

```
make_na(my_list, ~length(.x)==0)
```